# mssql checksum on different tables

Tags: sql-server

I need to find if two rows (one having the same id of the other +50000) are the same. Is there any way to make this query work?

```
select 1 
from table1 c1, 
     table2 c2 
where c1.id=c2.id+50000 and CHECKSUM(c1.*) = CHECKSUM(c2.*)
```

`CHECKSUM()` apparently does not accept `"table.*"` expressions. It accepts either `"*"` alone or list of columns, but I can't do that as this query needs to work also for other tables with other columns.

EDIT: I just realized that `CHECKSUM()` will not work as the value will always be different if the IDs are different....

The original question still holds out of curiosity.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE columnName IN (ID,ID+50000)`

Comment: CHECKSUM(*) will include the id column too in the checksum, so the 2 row checksums will differ even if all the columns except id are the same. So you can't use CHECKSUM() and have to compare every column (except id) explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, it will work for most datatypes (not TEXT and some others):

```
SELECT 1 
FROM
  table1 c1
JOIN 
  table2 c2 
ON 
  c1.id=c2.id+50000 and
  EXISTS(SELECT c1.col1, col2, col3, col4 EXCEPT SELECT c2.col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

Comment: You could `CAST` `TEXT` as `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using derived tables:

```
    SELECT 
            SUM(CASE
                WHEN a.cs <> b.cs THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END)
        FROM (SELECT RowNumber, CHECKSUM(*) AS cs FROM #A) a
        FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT RowNumber, CHECKSUM(*) AS cs FROM #B) b
            ON a.RowNumber=b.RowNumber;
```

This is an excerpt from a script I've written previously.  I have not changed any of the object names to match your example.   The result of this query is the number of differences between #A and #B where the RowNumber columns match.

To apply to your need, you can create two temporary tables, populating them from the originals, but replacing the ID column with a "RowNumber" column that matches between the rows you want to match (ie:   c1.id=c2.id+50000).   That way, you don't have mis-matched IDs to interfere with the CHECKSUM.